# What you need to know about Asynchronous JS Programming?

Tags: javascript, performance, node.js, asynchronous

I'm a web apps developer, I use for most apps PHP/MySQL with APC enabled, caching technologies: Memcached is my favorite one. Sometimes I use Percona MySQL version.

I'm new to NodeJS and I want to build my own web app using it. It's a SaaS working with Facebook, Twitter and Instagram APIs. I read a lot of good things about it.

What I need to know about Asynchronous JS Programming before starting the app?

Is there any performance advantages for Asynchronous Programming?

Is there any live examples, graphs with the difference between Async/Sync?

Comment: This question is way too generic. You need to know everything, and it's very hard, really.

Comment: Just read the docs or find a book.

Comment: This is not a helpful answer, I know there is a ton of books about NodeJS.

But in the start experts in NodeJS can tell what to start with, and what I need to know first.

Comment: @McShark: although this is an interesting question, this is more of an "opinion" question, where most answers would be considered somewhat correct, regardless of which side is taken, which is not really [what SO is all about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).  Perhaps [Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) would be more appropriate for such a topic.

Comment: Not much of opinion when considering just sync vs async, but even then the question is way too broad. The [Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) states: "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." and this is basically the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It doesn't block.

Let's compare with `PHP`:

```
<?
    readfile('some/large/file.bin');
?>
```

This might take a while. And while `PHP` reads the file, it won't be able to do other stuff (like answering other requests).

The same thing asynchonously (using `node.js`):

```
fs.readFile('/some/large/file.bin', function callback);
```

Node does the reading without `blocking` the current process.

So in conclusion: while the `synchronous` way blocks the process until the result is available, the `asynchronous` method has the advantage of doing other stuff, even before the `readFile` `callback` got fired.

Comment: require is sync afaik, so is the sync version of readFile `readFileSync`

Comment: yes, of course. I should have left this out. I mean only the `fs.readFile` part.

Comment: Oh of course, you're requiring `fs` to use `readFile` my bad. You can just comment those parts to make the difference more clear.

Comment: I just left the obvious `require` part out to avoid confusion :)

Comment: +1 for the simplistic overview. Could add a bit about working with callbacks which is basically the main aspect of async code, maybe some examples but yeah then that'd be a book for a not very constructive question.

Comment: +1 for letting my answer exist here :)

Comment: You've put effort into answering and it is an on-topic answer so there's no reason to delete it. `=]`